# Why is Pytest in an infinite loop when mocking `builtins.input`?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I want to test a function which calls `builtins.input`, so I have monkeypatched it. However, this seems to give an error which seems to repeat forever. What is going on?

Here is a test which reproduces the error:

```
import pytest

class TestA:

    def test_a(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda *a, **k: 'no')
        assert 0
```

And I want to run pytest like this:
`pytest --pdb tests/tmp.py`

The error is this:

```
...
*** NameError: name 'no' is not defined
*** NameError: name 'no' is not defined
*** NameError: name 'no' is not defined
*** NameError: name 'no' is not defined
...
```

Continuing forever.

Note that if I don't use the --pdb flag, it seems to work normally. But I want to use the --pdb flag as I find it useful for debugging.